# Determining the current Kerberos user in an Apache Spark job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, jaas

I'm running Spark jobs on a Kerberos-enabled cluster (Cloudera), and would like to be able to log the Kerberos identity of the user, for any given run of a job.

(Note that this is not the identity of the local Linux user that launches the job, because we use keytab files, `jaas.conf` files, and call `kinit` in the launch script. We can log an identity in the launch script, since we know the principal passed to `kinit` along with the keytab, but it would be nice to be able to log within the actual Spark job itself, so that even if a job is launched manually, we reliably know what identity it ran under).

Some answers suggest the following:

```
import java.security.{AccessController,Principal}
import javax.security.auth.Subject

val acc = AccessController.getContext
val sub = Subject.getSubject(acc)
val principals = sub.getPrincipals
```

but the returned `sub` is `null`, so this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the [`UserGroupInformation`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.html) class.

To get the logged-in user, you can use:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation

val user = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser

res6: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation = USER@REALM (auth:KERBEROS)
```